# Display date and time in comments

Tags: date-time, comments

I use wp_list_comments(); to display a list of comment in WordPress.

But it does show the format characters instead of the correct datetime. How can I fix this bug? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a callback or just writing it in the loop just like that? See here for what I mean about a callback: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments